# z-level error with tags and message boxes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

While reviewing a question, I decided to upvote it and noticed a white line on the blue warning box.  The picture can explain better than I can.

[image: white line]

It seems to line up to the left part of the tag.  I also reproduced it on a different question with multiple tags.

[image: 2 lines]

OS is Windows 7, browser is Firefox 28.0

Comment: Probably something to do with the unicorns?

Comment: @3ventic Possibly, someone without the perk might test and confirm though.

Comment: @3ventic Nah, happened way before already.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This issue is no longer reproducible following changes the tag design as part of the [Stack Exchange site design overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/179041). Arqade's changes were discussed [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13097/28182)